# Android Customized Camera

Tags: android, image-processing, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

Too much knowledge simply confuses you. I want to make a customized android camera application and as a novice I am unable to find exact help for my application because there is so much data related android camera applications that it becomes too confusing for me.

Here is a sample image where I just want to capture the three and stuff around it instead of the whole view. Zooming in and cropping wont work in my case since I want an irregular customized view in this case. And further more how should i start with? Creating an application that controls hardware camera or just use the default camera application for capturing and use my own application for image processing? Kindly if anyone can help out in this case. 
[image]

Comment: You need to perform image processing. Did you checked Open-CV? http://opencv.org/

Comment: Nops. I didn't. So what you are suggesting is that I should take a simple picture using default camera application and then perform image processing on that captures image?

Comment: To be honest i don't have any experience in OpenCV but do know that this kind of stuff can be achieved it via OpenCV do have algorithms to detect objects, shape, faces etc! You need to do bit of research on it.

Comment: Yes you can achieve some advantage by building "custom camera" app which will receive the preview stream from camera. Some object detection and segmentation algorithms work better on an image flow than on a single image. But you cannot instruct the hardware camera to do object detection for you, and do need computer vision algorithms to achieve your goal.

Comment: @AlexCohn My task isn't of detecting something. I guess I placed a little confusing picture. Don't focus on the three but on that irregular shape. I just want the image that comes inside this shape, be it a three or anything else.